# Select with a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to do a select on a join based on a non-standard foreign key. The SQL looks good but Rails isn't spitting out the results.

I have a Message model like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Person',
                      :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'Person',
                         :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end
```

and a Person model like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options :class_name => "Message", :dependent => :destroy,
               :order => 'created_at DESC' do |person|
    person.has_many :_sent_messages, :foreign_key => "sender_id",
                    :conditions => "sender_deleted_at IS NULL"
    person.has_many :_received_messages, :foreign_key => "recipient_id",
                    :conditions => "recipient_deleted_at IS NULL"
  end
end
```

If I query the table like this:

```
Message.joins(:sender).select('messages.id, people.latitude')
```

I get sensible SQL of the form:

```
"SELECT messages.id, people.latitude FROM \"messages\" INNER JOIN \"people\" ON \"people\".\"id\" = \"messages\".\"sender_id\""
```

This SQL executes fine in a console and returns results.

However my Rails result set looks like this

```
[#<Message id: 933>, #<Message id: 943>, #<Message id: 946>, ...]
```

No latitude or longitude values returned. The same query works fine if I use person_id as the foreign key. I'm using Postgres.

Why would this be, and how can I get the latitude and longitude values?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't your select use `person.latitude` and `person.longitude`?  Or thinking about does a Person belongs to the people table?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I modified the code to make it more legible. I'll update the question...

Comment: Are you just looking at the results from the console? Did you try `Message.joins(:sender).select('messages.id, people.latitude').first.latitude`?

Comment: It gets it, but it hits the database again.